# Views vs. EntityFieldQuery

Tags: views, database

Why would one use entityfieldquery over views? Is there any benefit to using EntityFieldQuery over using views? Is it the performance benefit? Is it the ease of use of a API? Does it provide you more granularity?

Answer (score 1):

It was recently written that there are several benefits over EFQ, entityfieldquery over other methods:

1. OOP - EntityFieldQuery provides an object oriented programming approach that allows you to create abstract classes to extend.
2. Flexibility - An advantaged arised from #1, creating your own objects allows you to modify the entitycontroller to do more things: Store field data via mongo DB, return data into blocks only, etc.

Source: http://chris-on-the-web.blogspot.com/2012/03/drupal-7-views-vs-entityfieldquery-pt1.html